# Named and anonymous exports in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is there a difference between exporting a react component as a named component (Method 1) and as an anonymous component (if that's what it's called) (Method 2)

Method 1:

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Named Export</div>
  }
}

export default MyClass
```

Method 2:

```
export default class extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Anonymous Export</div>
  }
}
```

Does React treat these two differently?

Comment: It's the same thing.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderPresber I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is different in both these.They both are working same, but for a connect-based Component you should use this format:

```
class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    );
  }
}
export default connect(Test)
```

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one default export per file. In React it's a convention to export one component from a file, and to export it is as the default export.
there is no difference if you export your component after declaring it.